# Get hrefs from google search in normal format - Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I am using Jsoup to parse google results and capture the links of each result but I have one problem, the links are in a weird format. For example, if you search the keyword "example" the first results give this format

```
https://www.google.gr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjhrPDwu9vJAhUJNhoKHekICmMQFgggMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FExample_(musician)&usg=AFQjCNGjbKpLZmpp_ce3TsCEHuJFh4ADVQ&sig2=fuONKdeA1R4X0TAEPVhjnQ&bvm=bv.109910813,d.d2s
```

instead of this:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example_%28musician%29
```

Any solutions of how to get the second result?

Answer (score 1):

have you checked the `data-href` attribute?

[image]

Comment: For some reason, there is no data-href attribute in my google results

Comment: mmh, try to use google's api for retrieving search results?

Comment: google's api have some restrictions, I would rather not use it

Comment: The `data-href` attribute is added on client side and it's not available.

Comment: @DavidePastore  Any thoughts of how to convert the url?